# many more complex problems vs. much more complex problems

Tags: grammar, usage

I think ***much*** in ***much more complex problems*** is grammatically correct because it modifies ***more complex*** though it convey a different meaning from ***many more complex problems***. Do you think my assumption to be right?

> (A)They are capable of solving ***many more complex problems***
>   compared to other birds, such as chickens.
>
> (B)They are capable of solving ***much more complex problems***
>   compared to other birds, such as chickens.

Comment: In B, **much** isn't an adverb or quantifier which are the usual usage. See [*much*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/much_1). And how does *much* modify "problems", as you say? "Much (complex) problems" makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possible interpretations that indicate what the sentences *could* be taken to mean.

> (A) They are capable of solving many more complex problems compared to other birds, such as chickens.

This means that they are capable of solving **many more problems** *that are* **complex**.

It's referring to quantity, not quality:

> (A) They can solve more problems of a complex nature than other birds.

---

Note that it *could* also be referring to a combination of quantity and quality:

> Then can solve *a lot* of problems of a more complex nature compared to other birds (who can only solve a few).

This is similar to the following interpretation, but subtly different.

---

> (B) They are capable of solving much more complex problems compared to other birds, such as chickens.

This means that they are capable of solving **problems** *that are* **much more complex**.

It's referring to quality, not quantity:

> (B) They can solve problems of a more complex nature than other birds.

Comment: @Araucaria Noted. I had wanted to provide a simple comparison. However, I've updated my answer to include this other sense.